# How to run in command line

Tags: java, apache, ofbiz

I'm a newbie in Java. and today i started learning Apache OFBiz. and then document have a paragraph is "Start the server by typing the following at the command line : java -Xmx256M -jar ofbiz.jar" . where command line and What I have to do ? 
i used Eclipse
Thanks very much!

Comment: That means "use a terminal"...

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès but my laptop run windown

Comment: ..which means use the windows-CMD. To use the mentioned command you have to navigate to the folder where your .jar is

Comment: @Tuan-IT there is a terminal on Windows... Terminal is a generic name for interactive command line interface application.

Comment: Open `CMD` program, change directory to ofbiz location and run this command: `ant.bat start`

Comment: If you use Eclipse, open 'ant' window, drag `build.xml` file from explorer and drop to `ant` window, find the `start` task and double-click

Answer (score 1):

Windows button + R, in the box type CMD and enter, that opens the command line. Then using cd, go to the location where your .jar is located, and execute the command.